# How can I do a log-in through ATATA

Tags: c#, selenium, atata

In Selenium, the following code is supposed to get you to an alert. Specifically, a log-in pop-up:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

How does this work using Atata?

Answer (score 0):

In Atata you can try to do the same by accessing the driver instance directly thru `AtataContext.Current.Driver`:

```
AtataContext.Current.Driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SetAuthenticationCredentials("username", "password");
```

But this WebDriver's functionality seems doesn't work in most current browsers.

Another approach is to pass credentials inside URL in a form of `https://user:pass@example.com/`. Tested recently in Chrome.

To do that with Atata you can set Atata base URL as `"https://example.com/"`. Then add the following method somewhere (in a base fixture class, for example):

```
public static void ApplyBasicAuth(string username, string password)
{
    Uri currentBaseUri = new Uri(AtataContext.Current.BaseUrl);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentBaseUri.UserInfo))
        AtataContext.Current.RestartDriver();

    UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(currentBaseUri)
    {
        UserName = username,
        Password = password
    };

    AtataContext.Current.BaseUrl = uriBuilder.ToString();
}
```

This method injects credentials into base URL.

Then in a test invoke it as a first arrangement action:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    ApplyBasicAuth("atuser", "atpass");

    Go.To<OrdinaryPage>();
    // ...
}
```